# Why would calling something from the foreground crash, when calling it from the background does not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, background-process

Ok, relatively new (again) to ObjectiveC, coming from a Swift background.  In our codebase, we have this line of code...

```
return _queryURL && ![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:_queryURL];
```

and while it works, when debugging, Xcode gives a warning stating `canOpenURL` must be executed from a foreground thread.

'Simple enough' I think... 'I'll just synchronously call it on the foreground thread!' and I update the code as follows...

```
__block BOOL result = NO;
  
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  result = _queryURL && ![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:_queryURL];
});

return result;
```

...but now, when executing the line which calls `canOpenURL`, I get this...

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Huh?!  Why would pushing it to the main thread cause an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` crash? Is that a red herring?

More importantly, how do you address this issue?

Comment: I think that (bad instruction) happens because you call ```dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue() ...``` from the main thread already. Just check ```NSThread.isMainThread``` if you are already on the main and then call it differently.

Comment: I think you're right.  BUT... can you put that in an answer so I can vote for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that *bad instruction* error happen when you `sync` call something on the main thread while you are *already* on the main thread.

I think, based on the error and the warning that you get, that you call this sometimes from the background and sometimes while on main. Thus you need to check using e.g.

```
NSThread.isMainThread
```

or similar before you call and then based on that proceed, maybe

```
if ( NSThread.isMainThread )
{
  // my call
}
else
{
  dispatch_sync( dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^ {
    // my call
  } );
}
```

However, if it is indeed the case that you sometimes call from main and sometimes from the background, you also need to verify that the logic behind it makes sense.

Comment: That was it!  Didn't realize it was being called a few times and sure enough, one was already on the main thread.

Comment: Great stuff Mark - glad I could help. I just edited my answer - you need to be sure it is fine as if you could call from either main or background it can lead to all sorts of trouble.

Comment: Here I suppose it is fine as I suspect sometimes you and sometimes some OS callback or event calls it, so it is natural that it can be mixed. But for 'normal' code, if there is such a thing, such calls could easily lead to concurrent modification errors.

Comment: Yeah.  I think the person who's calling it didn't realize they can't call the code from a background thread, but since they did it all basically synchronous, I can't simply change it to use async, and syncing to the main thread can be problematic.  My 'new' fix is to simply only update the variable if they're already *on* the main thread. If not, I use a static local to recall the value the last time it was on the main thread.  Perfect? No.  But it avoids the issue and allows us to set up a second 'refactor' task for the offending caller.

Comment: Yes - good code is an art, sometimes a very pragmatic one! At least, that is what I think ... Mark, hope you have a 'perfect' day.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the correct answer, I run into this often enough (usually in property observers) that I created a function for it:

```
void ExecuteOnMain( dispatch_block_t block )
{
    // Shorthand for synchronously executing a block on the main thread before returning.
    // Unlike dispatch_sync(), this won't deadlock if executed on the main thread.
    if (NSThread.isMainThread)
        block(); // main thread: execute the block immediately
    else
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),block); // not the main thread, queue the block
}
```

Then, all you have to write is

```
__block BOOL result = NO;
  
ExecuteOnMain(), ^{
  result = _queryURL && ![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:_queryURL];
});

return result;
```

Comment: Yes, but be very careful with this approach! Why? Consider the case where you're on the main thread, then you 'sync' to a background thread.  Now somewhere in that background thread, you execute your code above which attempts to sync back to the main thread, but it's already in a 'waiting' state.  You've just deadlocked your system!  You have to be very sure that the background thread you're currently on wasn't the result of syncing from the main thread.  If you can guarantee that, then you should be good to go.

Comment: This code solves exactly one problem: needing to run code that *must* be run on the main thread in a method that *doesn't know* which thread it was invoked from. That's it. All other multi-tasking, thread-safe, and dead-lock issues remain. :)